# RoR:2.3.8: Magical table, 'symbols', appears in DB? Where did it come from? why is it causing me issues?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

So, Here are some commands I ran:

```
% rake db:drop
% rake db:create
% rake db:migrate

==  SubscriptionGenesis: migrating ============================================
...le migrations...
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql::Error: Table 'myapp_dev.symbols' doesn't exist: ALTER TABLE `symbols` ADD `some_col` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 1
```

Now, my app has no table / model called symbols... and nothing about it in the schema.... so... I'm thrown for a loop. Where did it come from? My other rails apps don't appear to have the 'symbols' table =\

I searched through all teh db files, and there is no mention of "symbols", or :symbols anywhere (searched case insensitive), though I did find the table symbols in my schema file (which is generated)... so.. very weird.

EDIT: I just tried using sqlite. Same problem. =\ the line that it errors on is an add_column command.

Comment: rake db:migrate uses your migrations, not schema.rb. Search through those for "add_column :symbols, :some_col"

Comment: I searched through the whole db folder for symbols... no results.

Comment: Does running db:migrate with --trace yield any more insight?

Comment: wait... but it IS in the schema... what is going on there?

Comment: running with trace, not really. after droping the DB, and re-creating it. The error now occurs on one of the initial migrations, which hasn't been modified after its creation.

Comment: I just tried using sqlite. Same problem. =\ the line that it errors on is an add_column command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out, that it was because of how I extended the "object" class. In config/initializers, I had some object methods.

And there was a conflict apparently. Though it never told my anything about it.

So... Don't extend object in that folder, I guess.